# Combined Arrays won't display in single table line

Tags: php, arrays

I'm pulling data from two different tables in a database. Once I have all I need from both, I want combine the arrays and print data from each into an HTML table.

They both combine, but from it what it looks `array_merge` is appending the second array to the first array like it should. However, my problem is, when I create a table from the data in the new combined array, it will display all the fields I want from the first array on one line and all the data from the second array on a second line. Is there a way to force array_merge to 100% combine the array into one?

```php
$names = Array (
 [0] => Array (
  [PointID] => -3621
  [AddressID] => -503718
  [CommonName] => AARONS
  [MapDataID] => -2 
  [AlternateAddressID] => 
  [GISObjectID] => 28 
  [DateChanged] => 2013-06-19 13:48:44.947 
  [EnteredDate] => 2010-09-21 08:21:26.847
 )
)

$addressInfo= Array (
 [0] => Array (
  [AddressID] => -503718
  [LocationType] => 1
  [HouseNumber] => XXXX
  [AdditionalInfo] =>
  [...]
 )
)
```

Array once merged :

```php
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [PointID] => -3621 [AddressID] => -503718 [CommonName] => XXXXX )
 [1] => Array ( [AddressID] => -503718 [LocationType] => 1
  [HouseNumber] => XXXX [AdditionalInfo] => [StreetPrefix] => N
  [StreetPreType] => [StreetName] => XXXX [StreetType] => AVE
  [StreetSuffix] => [Apt] => [XStreetPrefix] => [XStreetPreType] =>
  [XStreetName] => [XStreetType] => [XStreetSuffix] => [VenueName] => XXXX
  [City] => XXXXX [vsState] => 52 [Zip] => XXXX )
)
```

Code:

```php
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>CN</th>
<th>House#</th>
<th>St Name</th>
<th>St Prefix</th>
<th>St Type</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>Zip</th>
</tr>";
//Combine the arrays into one
$output = array_merge($names, $addressInfo);
print_r($output);
//Run a loop   
foreach ($output as $test)
    {  
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$test['CommonName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$test['HouseNumber']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$test['StreetName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$test['StreetPrefix']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$test['StreetType']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$test['City']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$test['Zip']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm creating another answer to make this clearer.

Here is your current code :

```
$cn = "AARONS"; //Connect to NWSDB

$pdo = new PDO("odbc:NWS","docserver","docserver");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT CommonName,AddressID from CommonNameAddress where CommonName like :name");
$result->execute(array(':name' => "%$cn%"));
//Put the results in an array for use later in the table
$names = array();
$addquery = array();
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $addquery[] = $row['AddressID'];
    $names[] = $row;
}



$pdo = new PDO("odbc:NWS","docserver","docserver");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//Create an array for storing the address information from the below query
$addressInfo = array();
//Loop the query to get a result for every CommonName
foreach ($addquery as $address) {
    //Match the AddressID from the CommonNames Table to the Address information in the Address Table
    $common = $pdo->prepare("SELECT HouseNumber,StreetPrefix,StreetName,StreetType,City,Zip from Address where AddressID like :id");
    $common->execute(array(':id' => $address));
    //Put the results in an array for use later in the table
    while($row2 = $common->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { $addressInfo[] = $row2; }
}
```

Here is what you could do :

```
$cn = "AARONS"; //Connect to NWSDB

$pdo = new PDO("odbc:NWS","docserver","docserver");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT CommonName, CommonNameAddress.AddressID, Address.HouseNumber, Address.StreetPrefix, Address.StreetName, Address.StreetType, Address.City, Address.Zip from CommonNameAddress LEFT JOIN Address ON Address.AddressID=CommonNameAddress.AddressID where CommonName like :name");
$result->execute(array(':name' => "%$cn%"));
//Put the results in an array for use later in the table
$names = array();
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $names[] = $row;
}
print_r($names);
?>
```

Tell us how it goes.

Comment: Damn! That works great! Thanks soooo much! I finally figured it out myself with a for loop, but your method is a billion times more efficient so I'm going with that!! Thanks again!

Comment: Coool :-) Please upvote my answer. And good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your 2 arrays `$names` and `$addressInfo` already contain another level of data.

You might want to do this :

```
$output = array_merge($names[0], $addressInfo[0]);
```

If it doesn't work, please provide `print_r()` output of both `$names` and `$addressInfo` before you merge them.

Comment: Man that was sooooooo close. I changed your line to:

    `$output[] = array_merge($names[0], $addressInfo[0]);`


That fixed it, but the issue with that is it's only returning the one line of results.

Comment: Just give us `print_r($names)` and `print_r($addressInfo)`, and we will be able to help you.

Comment: $names =

    `Array ( [0] => Array ( [PointID] => -3621 [AddressID] => -503718 [CommonName] => AARONS [MapDataID] => -2 [AlternateAddressID] => [GISObjectID] => 28 [DateChanged] => 2013-06-19 13:48:44.947 [EnteredDate] => 2010-09-21 08:21:26.847 ) )`

Comment: $addressInfo=


    `Array ( [0] => Array ( [AddressID] => -503718 [LocationType] => 1 [HouseNumber] => XXXX [AdditionalInfo] => [StreetPrefix] => N [StreetPreType] => [StreetName] => XXXXX [StreetType] => AVE [StreetSuffix] => [Apt] => [XStreetPrefix] => [XStreetPreType] => [XStreetName] => [XStreetType] => [XStreetSuffix] => [VenueName] => XXXX [City] => XXXX [vsState] => 52 [Zip] => XXXXX  ) )`

Comment: «  That fixed it, but the issue with that is it's only returning the one line of results. » Ok. But it's the only things that are in your arrays... Maybe you should change your SQL queries, or make a SQL join instead of merge theses 2 arrays. Can you show us the previous code?

Comment: I'd love to do one query, because then I could just do a normal `while` loop and call it a day. The data I want is in two different tables. One table has the `CommonName` and `AddressID` you see in $names array, then I have to take the `AddressID` and select the entry that matches it to pull all that data from second table. I've tried many different ways from other posts on here to make them truly into one array, but I can't seem to get them to merge 100%.

Comment: Or if there is a way to just add the results from the second query directly into the first array. I'm assuming that would solve the problem as well..

Comment: Show use the 2 queries. I'll help you make a join query to make it simpler.

Comment: Have to split it in three to fit. Part one:

`$cn = "AARONS";

//Connect to NWSDB
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:NWS","docserver","docserver");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT CommonName,AddressID from CommonNameAddress where CommonName like :name");
$result->execute(array(':name' => "%$cn%"));

//Put the results in an array for use later in the table
$names = array();
$addquery = array();
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
   $addquery[] = $row['AddressID'];
   $names[] = $row;
  }`

Comment: `$pdo = new PDO("odbc:NWS","docserver","docserver");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Create an array for storing the address information from the below query
$addressInfo = array();

//Loop the query to get a result for every CommonName
foreach ($addquery as $address)
{
//Match the AddressID from the CommonNames Table to the Address information in the Address Table
$common = $pdo->prepare("SELECT HouseNumber,StreetPrefix,StreetName,StreetType,City,Zip from Address where AddressID like :id");
$common->execute(array(':id' => $address));`

Comment: `//Put the results in an array for use later in the table
while($row2 = $common->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
   $addressInfo[] = $row2;
  }}`